# Hole doping in BSCCO

Tags: superconductivity

I read literature about superconductor BSCCO ($Bi_2Sr_2CuO_{7-x}$) and came across a very interesting term.
It is said that the process of removing oxygen atoms, in which a pure substance becomes a superconductor, is called hole doping.
I do not quite understand this term in relation to this situation. Oxygen is removed completely (along with the electrons), the total charge of the system does not change.
Do they mean holes like in semiconductors?

Experts, please explain what this term means in relation to this situation.

Comment: Are you familiar with p-doping and n-doping of semiconductors? I'm pretty sure it's the same thing here.

Comment: Of course, I am familiar with this term. If so, then this is a rather strange principle of doping - to remove an atom, and not replace it with some kind of donor. I have never met this before, therefore, I decided to clarify this issue.

Comment: Vacancies do not change the doping in monatomic materials (like Silicon) for the most part, but they certainly dopes materials with atoms with different electronegativities like CdTe or GaAs. Let me do a look into this weird material "Bi2Sr2CuO7-x" and see if it is the same. My guess is Oxygen binds two electrons to get a $2-$ state like usual and when you have oxygen missing then those two electrons are free to move (effectively adding 2 carriers to conduction band).

Comment: I also now met such a designation for a substance - " $Bi_2Sr_2CuO_{6+x}$" and on wiki you can find the following "BSCCO needs to be hole-doped by an excess of oxygen atoms (x in the formula) in order to superconduct". So what then is meant by hole doping? adding an oxygen atom to $Bi_2Sr_2CuO_{6+x}$ or removing an oxygen atom from a  $Bi_2Sr_2CuO_{7-x}$ substance? Apparently, these are not contradictory things, but I have not yet realized this detail

Comment: Maybe this fact will lead you to the idea of an explanation: this superconductor consists of several perovskite blocks. And in the perovskite structure, an oxygen atom, as a rule, plays the role of an anion.